# Prevent overwriting of variable names during replacement in an R list

Tags: r

This question is related to one I asked recently:

[Replace multiple Instances of a variable name in an R function and save the modified function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77801581/replace-multiple-instances-of-a-variable-name-in-an-r-function-and-save-the-modi/77801694#77801694).

Now, I need to efficiently modify names within an R list, but the way in which the names need to be modified results in duplicate variables with different values being created.

Here is my code:

```
NF <- NM <- JF <- JM <- 0

# Create the list
res <- list("NF" = NF, "NM" = NM, "JF" = JF, "JM" = JM)

# Replace variables in the YAML content
variables_to_replace <- names(res)
new_variables <- c("JF", "JM", "SubAF", "SubAM")

for (i in seq_along(variables_to_replace)) {
  names(res)[names(res) == variables_to_replace[i]] <- new_variables[i]
}
```

The problem appears to be that the variables `"JF"` and `"JM"` both appear in the `variables_to_replace` and `new_variables` vectors. So, in the case of the first appearance of `"JF"' for instance, it will become` "SubAF"` on the second pass.

Note this is a small example. In my actual code containing many variables names, names contained in `variables_to_replace` often appear in other variable names such as `GammaNF`, which would need to be changed to `GammaJF` as per requirements. I think this is where my linked post could be useful (*i.e*, use of `gsub()` or other regex functions

Comment: I think at this point you should step back and reevaluate your requirements: *why* do you need to change the names of local variables in functions? This is a distinctly odd requirement, and I’d wager that you are making your life more difficult than necessary.

Comment: Also consider the `ymlthis` package..

Comment: It's a bit difficult for us to help modifying a YAML file whose structure we know nothing about. Can you make this question reproducible?

Comment: @r2evans I have modified the code to work on an R list instead of a YAML file. The end result is the same. It should be straightforward to make this work for a YAML file on my end.

Answer (score 1):

I really prefer having a clear pairing for old-to-new names, so instead of two vectors we'll have one named-vector:

```r
res <- list("NF" = 0, "NM" = 0, "JF" = 0, "JM" = 0)
vars <- c("JF"="NF", "JM"="NM", "SubAF"="JF", "SubAM"="JM")
m <- na.omit(setNames(match(vars, names(res)), names(vars)))
m
#    JF    JM SubAF SubAM 
#     1     2     3     4 
names(res)[m] <- names(m)
str(res)
# List of 4
#  $ JF   : num 0
#  $ JM   : num 0
#  $ SubAF: num 0
#  $ SubAM: num 0
```

Notes:

- `match(.)` returns the position within `names(res)` of the matches
- if for some reason one of `new_variables` is not pre-existing, then `match` will return `NA`; since we use `na.omit`, this will be removed; since the vector is named with the new variable names, then we won't try to to that renaming

Example with mis-match:

```r
res <- list("NF" = 0, "NM" = 0, "JF" = 0, "JM" = 0)
vars <- c("JF"="NF@@@", "JM"="NM", "SubAF"="JF", "SubAM"="JM")
m <- na.omit(setNames(match(vars, names(res)), names(vars)))
m
#    JM SubAF SubAM 
#     2     3     4 
# attr(,"na.action")
# JF 
#  1 
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "omit"
names(res)[m] <- names(m)
str(res)
# List of 4
#  $ NF   : num 0
#  $ JM   : num 0
#  $ SubAF: num 0
#  $ SubAM: num 0
```

This of course highlights the potential for inconsistency in whatever process is expected, so for resiliency you may want a follow-on check:

```r
stopifnot(all(names(vars) %in% names(res)))
# Error: all(names(vars) %in% names(res)) is not TRUE
```

where this passed on the first code block above.

Comment: Thanks. It seems the solution needs slight modification for my purpose. For example, I have a variable called `GammaNF` which would need to be changed to `GammaJF`; that is, the code should also handle partial matching. I think the `pmatch()` function should do the trick.

Comment: There's nothing in your post or attempted code that suggests patterns.